# Как поставить canvas на Nodejs + docker?

Tags: node.js, canvas, docker-compose, dockerfile

Пытаюсь поставить canvas на nodejs по [инструкции](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas)

получаю ошибку

```
    /usr/src/app $ npm  i canvas
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /usr/src/app/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --update-binary
npm ERR! Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --update-binary --module=/usr/src/app/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/usr/src/app/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v111' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.10
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@19.4.0 | linux | arm64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.11.2/canvas-v2.11.2-node-v111-linux-musl-arm64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.11.2/canvas-v2.11.2-node-v111-linux-musl-arm64.tar.gz 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for canvas@2.11.2 and node@19.4.0 (node-v111 ABI, musl) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.11.2/canvas-v2.11.2-node-v111-linux-musl-arm64.tar.gz
```

Dockerfile

```
###################
# BUILD FOR LOCAL DEVELOPMENT
###################
FROM node:19.4-alpine3.16 As development

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -qq build-essential libcairo2-dev libpango1.0-dev libjpeg-dev libgif-dev librsvg2-dev

# Copy application dependency manifests to the container image.
# A wildcard is used to ensure copying both package.json AND package-lock.json (when available).
# Copying this first prevents re-running npm install on every code change.
COPY --chown=node:node package*.json ./
COPY --chown=node:node prisma ./prisma/

# Install app dependencies using the `npm ci` command instead of `npm install`
RUN npm ci

# Bundle app source
COPY --chown=node:node . .

# Use the node user from the image (instead of the root user)
USER node
```

Comment: у вас образ `node:19.4-alpine3.16` основан на `alpine`, а команды `apt-get install ...` вы изсользуете из `debian`, может нужно перейти на debian-based образ?